# symbol(s) not found for architecture i386 in SDWebImageDownloader

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa, linker

When i'am trying to compile with Xcode i get the following errors:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_CGImageSourceCopyPropertiesAtIndex", referenced from:
      -[SDWebImageDownloader connection:didReceiveData:] in SDWebImageDownloader.o
  "_CGImageSourceCreateImageAtIndex", referenced from:
      -[SDWebImageDownloader connection:didReceiveData:] in SDWebImageDownloader.o
  "_CGImageSourceCreateIncremental", referenced from:
      -[SDWebImageDownloader connection:didReceiveData:] in SDWebImageDownloader.o
  "_CGImageSourceUpdateData", referenced from:
      -[SDWebImageDownloader connection:didReceiveData:] in SDWebImageDownloader.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_MFMailComposeViewController", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in MWPhotoBrowser.o
  "_kCGImagePropertyPixelHeight", referenced from:
      -[SDWebImageDownloader connection:didReceiveData:] in SDWebImageDownloader.o
  "_kCGImagePropertyPixelWidth", referenced from:
      -[SDWebImageDownloader connection:didReceiveData:] in SDWebImageDownloader.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

There must be a problem with SDWebImage class, which MWPhotoBrowser use.
This is really strange and confusing, and I don't know how to fix it.

Thanks guys.

Comment: Please check  

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12306161/build-fail-when-using-sdwebimage

it works for me

Answer (score 57, accepted):

The problem is most likely that the project is not including the ImageIO framework. Go to your Target -> Build Phases -> Link and verify that in fact you have ImageIO there.

Comment: +1 Thanks, worked for me. I got same error while adding [MWPhoto](https://github.com/mwaterfall/MWPhotoBrowser) in my project. :)

Answer (score 2):

I think that i have the solution...

Go to to the **target** of your app and on the right, click on the **Build Phases** tab and in the **Compile Sources** Section click on **+** and add the `SDWebImage.m`

Hope that helps !