# Linker error for imported header file Xcode 4.5

Tags: objective-c, xcode4.5

I have downloaded a header file and static library file (.a file) from the internet. They are provided by the wireless printer which i bought for my iphone and trying to make print functionality working in my app. The problem is when I run the sample app provided by them to test printer, I get the following linker error...Obviously the app was designed in the previous versions of Xcode and Im using Xcode 4.5. Much appreciated if someone could Guide me..[image]

Comment: Hello, can you kindly tell me how you got hold of libwspr240.a? This is the static library for Woosim bluetooth printer. Did you have to mail them to get the sample? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are building an iOS project and it's using the `i386` architecture, then you must be building for the simulator. What happens when you build for an actual iOS device?

It's possible that the library was compiled only for the processor architectures for real iOS devices, typically `armv6`, `armv7`, or `armv7s`. You can use the `file` command in Terminal to see what architectures are in the `.a` library file.

Answer (score 0):

Check these answers [Symbols not found for architecture i386?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10107920/symbols-not-found-for-architecture-i386) and [symbols not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11900848/symbols-not-found-for-architecture-i386-in-sdwebimagedownloader).

Check your **project-> build phases -> Link Binary With Libraries** whether there is `libwspr240.a` file is there or not.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `libwspr240.a` file and then readd it using

`Project --> Build Phases --> Link Binary with Libraries` click `'+'` button to add.

Then **Clean** and **Build** the project